# Laravel - multiple boot override

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

In my laravel project I want to use an trait for use an `uuid` for the primary keys and make a cascade delete.

There is 2 models : `User` and `Box`.

An `user` can have many `Box` and a `Box` can have many `Box` too.
Because I use mysql, the `onDelete('cascade')` not work and I need it.

So I override the `Boot` method of my models to force it, but now, the Boot method of my trait (`UuidIdentifiable`) cannot be called.

The utility of this trait is to generate an `uuid` for primary key when I create a new model.

Now, when I want to create a model, when Eloquent insert the values, the database return an error because the `Id` of my models is null.

So, override the `Boot` on a model should override the `Boot` of the traits but how to get the functionnality of the custom `Boot` method of my trait and of my models too ?

```
<!-- language: php -->
class Box extends Model
{
    use UuidIdentifiable;

    protected $fillable = ['label', 'parent_box_id', 'user_id'];
    protected $guarded = [];
    public $incrementing = false;

    public function owner() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
    }

    public function parent() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Box', 'parent_box_id');
    }

    public function boxes (){
        return $this->hasMany('App\box', 'parent_box_id', 'id');
    }

    protected static function boot() {
        parent::boot();

        static::deleting(function(Box $box) {
            $box->boxes()->delete();
        });
    }
}

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable, UuidIdentifiable;
    public $incrementing = false;

    protected $fillable = ['username', 'email', 'password'];

    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];

    public function boxes (){
        return $this->hasMany('App\box', 'user_id', 'id');
    }

    protected static function boot() {
        parent::boot();

        static::deleting(function(User $user) {
            $user->boxes()->delete();
        });
    }
}

trait UuidIdentifiable
{
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::creating(function ($model) {
            $model->{$model->getKeyName()} = Uuid::generate()->string;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Would it be acceptable to rename the `boot` method on the trait to something like `assignUuid` and call it in the model's `boot` method?

Comment: I found this http://www.archybold.com/blog/post/booting-eloquent-model-traits I will try later, thank you by the way, I think it can resolve by problem !

Comment: Cool, didn't know about the bootable trait magic. That should do it for you. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. Perhaps provide this solution as an answer post to your own question for others with the same problem?

Answer (score 5):

just use this trick:

```
namespace App\Traits;

trait UuidIdentifiable
{
    protected static function bootUuidIdentifiable()
    {
        static::creating(function ($model) {
            $model->{$model->getKeyName()} = Uuid::generate()->string;
        });
    }
}
```

so, if you change `boot` to `bootYourTraitName` and `remove` boot function from the model,  I think your problem will solve.

It's a best practice to write traits in a separate file and just use them in models.
It's better to don't create a boot function in models.

---

#### Summary:

1. Make a directory in `app` folder with this name: `Traits`
2. Make a file in `app/Traits` with this name: `UuidIdentifiable`
3. Write your own trait. just notice you should name your boot function with this syntax: `bootYourTraitName`
4. use traits in every model you want.

Comment: Hi, Can you explain further on how this thing works?